# Spring Boot Social Twitter Authentication fails

Tags: spring-boot, twitter-oauth, spring-social, spring-oauth2, spring-social-twitter

I have a project on Spring Boot, in which I need to implement authorization via Twitter.

What could be simpler? - I asked myself, and then I got stuck for a few days.

The problem is that the most of the libraries I've tried (listening for /connect/twitter or /signin/twitter) return the same response

```
Invalid cookie header: "set-cookie: personalization_id=""; Expires=Tue, 28 Jul 2020 20:04:39 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Tue, 28 Jul 2020 20:04:39 GMT
```

My attention was attracted by the phrase:

```
Invalid 'expires' attribute
```

this can be solved by configuring RestTemplate, but the problem is that it is deeply created in the configurations and hidden by the private final fields. 
I think that there should exist a decision better than playing with reflection API, I just don't see it

Perhaps someone will be able to suggest the correct way of authorization through Twitter.

Tested Versions:

- Spring Boot versions from 1.5.14 to 2.0.3
- org.springframework.social:spring-social-twitter from 1.1.2 to 2.0.0.M4
- spring-boot-starter-social-twitter up to 2.0.0.M4

P.S. Facebook was perfectly working with spring-security-oauth2-jose and spring-security-oauth2-client, but twitter is not configured as a provider in it

> Provider ID must be specified for client registration 'twitter'

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need to configure the `RestTemplate` to use the standard cookie spec. This could be achieved by setting the cookieSpec on the `RequestConfig.Builder` and then via the `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` to finally create the `RestTemplate`.
Somethning like:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
        .build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    factory.mergeRequestConfig(requestConfig);

    return new RestTemplate(factory);
}
```

Sorry, currently I don't have an IDE/javac available so this might not compile.

Comment: This could be a solution, but ConnectController use its own instance of RestTemplate and I can't override it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to configure your RestTemplate Bean to use standard cookie specs

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());
}

private HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    clientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(getHttpClient());
    return clientHttpRequestFactory;
}

private HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    return HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
            .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build())
            .build();
}
```